# Question of derivability

Tags: partial-differential-equations

i want to prove that $-\partial_xV(x)\partial_v f-|v|^2_{/4} f -f$ is in $C^\infty(R^{2n})$ for f $\in$ $L^2(R^{2n})$ and $V$ is in $C^\infty(R^{n})$ where $(x,v)\in R^{2n}$ and f satisfies $\partial_xV(x)\partial_v f-|v|^2_{/4} f -f=-v.\partial_xf-\partial_v^2f$ in $D'(R^{2n})$ .Can someone please help me?thanks.

Comment: 'Need help with a question' is not a proper title. It doesn't tell anything about the content of your question, you need to edit it

Answer (score 0):

**Hint(1):** Expand all terms of your function in terms of partial derivatives of $f$ and $V$

**Hint(2):** Multiplication of smooth functions is still smooth the same for taking linear combinations.

Comment: the terms of the function are not already expanded in terms of partial derivatives of $f$ and $V$?

Comment: From what you have writen - no, because $\partial_x V$ is rather directional derivative in direction of vector $x$.

Comment: so i should write :$\sum_{i=0}^n$ $-\partial_x_iV(x)\partial_v_i f-|v|^2_{/4} f -f$ ?

Comment: $\partial_x V (x)= \sum_{i=1}^n\partial_{x_i} V (x) x_i$

Comment: and then what should i do?

Comment: apply hint 1 to other derivatives and than hint 2

Comment: we have also $\partial_v f(x,v)= \sum_{i=1}^n\partial_{v_i} f (x,v) v_i$ and this is all we can do in hint 1

Comment: for hint 2 you said that Multiplication of smooth functions is still smooth the same for taking linear combinations.but i see only $\partial_x V (x)$ is $C^\infty$ since V is $C^\infty$

Comment: Yes, and all you need to observe is that partial derivatives of $f$ and $V$ are smooth since they were smooth

Comment: for hint 2 you said that Multiplication of smooth functions is still smooth the same for taking linear combinations.but i see only $\partial_x V (x)$ is $C^\infty$ since V is $C^\infty$

Comment: o I see you have writen $f  \in L^2$ but that is to little in order to write $\partial_v f$, are you shure that $f \in L^2$?

Comment: yes we have $f \in L^2(R^{2n})$ and i have also f satisties -$\partial_xV(x)\partial_v f-|v|^2_{/4} f -f=-v.\partial_xf-\partial_v^2f$ in $D'(R^{2n})$but i dont know if that will help in the question

Comment: Well that changes things complitely ...

Comment: how that will help?

Comment: J.E.M.S, can you please help me more?

Comment: Right now I can't solve that problem, but certainly the statement of your first post without information you have given above is not true.

Comment: In fact i want to prove that the right hand of the equality is in $C^\infty(R^{2n})$ so that we have f is in $C^\infty(R^{2n}) $since the Hormander operator of type 2 in the left hand of the equality is hypoelliptic.but i dont no how i will do that.

Comment: you can finf the problem in page 45 in this web site:https://books.google.fr/books?id=RrjMCiecRWIC&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=fokker+planck+operator+is+positive&source=bl&ots=yBQsWS-K-d&sig=P9S3xiwinmNJqJT77dL-I-mMc2A&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjw1ZrsmNnLAhXmHpoKHSf_A_sQ6AEILjAC#v=onepage&q=fokker%20planck%20operator%20is%20positive&f=false